# Facebook Graph API returns no content (empty data array)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I'm using Python's `requests` to extract data from Facebook pages using Facebook Graph API as follows -

```
r = requests.request("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/VisaUnitedStates/feed", params={'until':1364423876, 'access_token':oath_access_token, 'limit':900})
r.content
'{"data":[]}'
```

But it returns an empty data array as seen above. Same query works fine in Facebook graph explorer, so there is no issue related to permissions (Also, I've added all the permissions to the access_token). What can be the problem here?

I've seen many other similar questions, but nothing is helping me here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the facebook page for which you are making the request is public, the **access token** could not be the issue; since any valid access token works for reading the public pages feed.

The problem is with the **until** parameter I guess. Check the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/), there is no such paramter `until`. So, if you want to get the feeds upto a certain time, you should use the FQL query instead using `created_time` parameter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But when I use user token instead of app token, it gives me proper results. Also, In Facebook graph explorer, there is a parameter `until` and it works well (there I got the idea of using it in my script). So, when I need to get posts for a page like `walmart` (for a year), which token would do you suggest me to use?

Comment: As I told, app access token will fetch you all the public post of any page in facebook. The user access token will be required for the posts that are not ublic but visible to that user

Comment: Thank you, one last thing. Can you please tell me why should I use `FQL` instead of making `http` requests to graph to get the data? Also, when I see page feed and graph explorer and turn the page to see more content it uses `until` present in the `next` of `paging`. That is what I was following, where do you think the issue is in this approach?

Comment: Well that's fine too, fql was just an alternative :) Since I had played with conditions on created_time with fql only